# Convert phasors to sinusoidal waveform

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to convert this phasor into a sinusoidal waveform.

$$
j6e^{-j\pi/4}
$$

Here's what I have so far:

$$
6\sin(\omega t-\pi/4) = 6\cos(\omega t-\pi/4 - \pi/2) = 6\cos(\omega t-3\pi/4)
$$
but apparently this is wrong. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
j 6 e^{-j \pi /4} = e^{j \pi/2} 6 e^{-j \pi /4}= 6 e^{j \pi /4} $$
So the answer is $6 \cos(w t + \pi/4)$. You are off by $\pi$.

Comment: Totally forgot about j contributing that 90 degrees. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The relations you need are $j = e^{j\pi/2}$, $e^{j\alpha} e^{j\beta} = e^{j(\alpha + \beta)}$, and

$$
e^{j\phi} = \cos(\phi)+j \sin(\phi)
$$

Use these and you'll get your answer.